# Re-Partitioning to Save My Data

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I put about 1.5Tb of data on a 6T HDD, EXT4 format external USB drive, to bring halfway around the world. After I arrived, Ubuntu 18.04 does not "see" the drive when it is plugged into my laptop. The drive is not dead and communicates, but no access to data. I'm getting conflicting information from Ubuntu disk operation commands (below). Some say 1.6TB. Some say 5.5TB. HELP! How do I go about fixing this?

Refer to the last six or so lines in this post. There is a partitioning tool for windows, Aoemei Partition Assistant, which sees both partitions, but I don't know what to do to FIX the issue. I'm sure I only get one shot at fixing this and being able to use the data while I am here for another five months. It's all backed up, but it's 5000 miles away. Thanks in advance for assistance. I'm currently on GMT.

gparted says "The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used." It then says the entire drive is one partition that is 1.46 Tb UNALLOCATED.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 1.5 TiB, 1603128614912 bytes, 3131110576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1           1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT
Command (m for help): v
Total allocated sectors 4294967296 greater than the maximum 3131110576.
Command (m for help): F
Unpartitioned space /dev/sdc: 0 B, 0 bytes, 0 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

```
sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3
Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.
Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged
************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
************************************************************************
Command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 3131110576 sectors, 1.5 TiB
Model: FANTOM DRIVE    
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 46236-STUFF-77
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 11721045134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3181 sectors (1.6 MiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048     11721043967   5.5 TiB     8300  Seagate6T

Command (? for help): r
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): i
Using 1
Partition GUID code: 0FC63D-STUFF-E4 (Linux filesystem)
Partition unique GUID: E72007-STUFF-46
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 11721043967 (at 5.5 TiB)
Partition size: 11721041920 sectors (5.5 TiB) 
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'Seagate6T'
Recovery/transformation command (? for help): x
Expert command (? for help): v
Caution: The CRC for the backup partition table is invalid. This table may
be corrupt. This program will automatically create a new backup partition
table when you save your partitions.

Problem: The secondary header's self-pointer indicates that it doesn't reside at the end of the disk. If you've added a disk to a RAID array, use the 'e' option on the experts' menu to adjust the secondary header's and partition table's locations.

Problem: Disk is too small to hold all the data!
(Disk size is 3131110576 sectors, needs to be 11721045168 sectors.)
The 'e' option on the experts' menu may fix this problem.

Problem: GPT claims the disk is larger than it is! (Claimed last usable
sector is 11721045134, but backup header is at 11721045167 and disk size is 3131110576 sectors.
The 'e' option on the experts' menu will probably fix this problem

Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.

Partition(s) in the protective MBR are too big for the disk! Creating a
fresh protective or hybrid MBR is recommended.

Identified 6 problems!Command (? for help): x

Expert command (? for help): e
Relocating backup data structures to the end of the disk

Expert command (? for help): w
Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by
8589933425 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.
Problem: partition 1 is too big for the disk.
Aborting write operation!
Aborting write of new partition table.
```

Comment: You are caught in a loop. You cannot resize since table corrupt & you cannot fix table since it overlaps. Only solution is to delete table (data still exists), recreate slightly smaller & repair. Do not reformat & that would erase data, just resize. Similar issues: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1956173 Best to have really good backups.

Comment: I think you should rebuild the protective MBR first, can be done with the `n` option in the experts menu. That should fix the overlap problem. Use the `o`-option in the recovery menu first to print protective MBR data. The protective MBR should hold only one partition which spans over the whole disk which is obviosly not the case.

Comment: mook765 - This is what I did and saw...sudo gdisk /dev/sdc
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
Warning! Secondary partition table overlaps the last partition by 33 blocks!
You will need to delete this partition or resize it in another utility.

Comment: Recovery/transformation command (? for help): o
Disk size is 3131110576 sectors (1.5 TiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1   4294967295   primary     0xEE

Comment: Recovery/transformation command (? for help): p
Disk /dev/sdc: 7833600 sectors, 3.7 GiB
Model: Flash Disk      
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 0E...291BA
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 7833566
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3158 sectors (1.5 MiB)
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            3192         7833599   3.7 GiB     0700  Microsoft basic data

Comment: Note that start and end sector numbers are not even close.

Comment: Recovery/transformation command (? for help): o
Disk size is 7833600 sectors (3.7 GiB)
MBR disk identifier: 0x00000000
MBR partitions:
Number  Boot  Start Sector   End Sector   Status      Code
   1                     1      7833599   primary     0xEE

Comment: Recovery/transformation command (? for help): x
Expert command (? for help): ?
[...]
n create a new protective MBR
[...]

Comment: I QUIT and did not write after the "n" command. If I create a NEW protective MBR, will it destroy whatever FAT information the old one contains?

Comment: SOLVED: On advice from an expert, I put the drive in a desktop computer running Linux and was able to access the data. His notes: "If I had to guess, I'd say that you prepared your disk by installing it inside a desktop or laptop computer and then put it in an external enclosure (a "FANTOM DRIVE").

Comment: The trouble is that most (maybe all) USB enclosures have a 32-bit sector address limit, which means they can contain no more than 2^32 (4,294,967,296) sectors -- but your disk has 11,721,043,967 sectors. Thus, the disk size "rolls over" every 2^32 sectors, as far as the computer can see, and appears to be 1.5 TiB in size.
AFAIK, there is NO WAY to retrieve your data from the hard disk while it
is installed in this enclosure. Three ways around this problem spring to
mind:

Comment: * Move the hard disk out of the Fantom Drive enclosure and into a
  desktop or laptop computer, similar to the way I'm guessing you prepared it. The data should then be accessible again."  This is SORT OF what happened. The Fantom Drive has two I/O ports, one USB and one eSATA. I originally used the eSATA cable that came with the drive to run into my desktop box and transferred my data that way, thinking it would be faster. It never occurred to me that the USB port would then fail to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

Move the hard disk out of the Fantom Drive enclosure and into a desktop computer. The Fantom Drive has two ports, one eSATA and one USB. If the drive is formatted and stuffed with data via the eSATA port, in my case it was not be readable via the USB port. Relocating the drive inside a desktop box worked for me.